# If you throw a red shell in first place, where does it go?

Tags: mario-kart-8

If you throw a red shell while in first place, who will it try to hit? It does try to hit whoever is a place above you, but if nobody is above you, what does it do?

Comment: Best info I could manage to google is that *depending on which game*, the red shell will either travel straight forward until it hits a wall or other item, or follow the track until it hits something (with no homing ability)... I couldn't seem to narrow down which of the two MK8 uses...

Comment: When you're in first place, the red shell doesn't try to hit anyone, since there is no one in front. Like @TrentHawkins said, it either follows the track for a while or until it hits something, or travels straight into a wall.

Comment: As Nolonar said, Trent already said that all three of us don't know.

Comment: IIRC you can also throw it backwards and it will home in on whoever is behind you. Could be wrong though.

Comment: @CommandoAir launching a red shell backwards has one of three effects, depending on game; ***1***) it will travel in a straight line backwards until it hits something, ***2***) it becomes a stationary obstacle, ***3***) it becomes a stationary obstacle until a kart gets close enough - at which point it activates and homes in on that kart.

Comment: Typically, I find best practices for having a red shell in first place is to drag it behind as protection from other red shells. Keeping it until someone dares to try and pass you, only firing it off (forward or behind) if a blue shell is coming to wreck your day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you throw a red shell forwards while in first place, it follows the track for a little bit but does not home in on any player.

If you throw a red shell backwards while in first place, it acts exactly like a green shell does when thrown back, traveling in a straight line.

If you have a red shell while in first place, it's best to keep it trailing behind you to block red shells and to deter any opponents from passing you.

Comment: You don't have to be in first place necessarily, when you throw a red shell behind you, it will always act as a green shell regardless if what place you're in.